# On dual-boot rig, wifi internet working on win10 but not on ubuntu 18

Tags: wireless, asus

My laptop is ASUS rog scar3.

- Wifi is working fine and connects to every wifi spot I usually connect to except in `home wifi`. It is showing that it is connected and have an ip address, but I cannot get access to any of the web pages. ping 8.8.8.8 sometimes gets response and sometimes getting `host unreachable`.
- Also I cannot ping the gateway `192.168.1.1`
- My default dns server was `192.168.1.1` Tried to change the default DNS server with `nmcli`: `set ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` but no luck.
- I reinstalled the wireless hardware `Intel Wireless-AC 9560` in `/lib/firmware`, but also does not help.
- `git pull` also does not work throwing: `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bla/bla.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com`.
- I can connect to `home wifi` with my mac and iphone. Also it is working well and having internet access when connecting with the asus scar3 when booting from win10, but not the ubuntu.

Tried nearly every possible solution (old and new) with no luck.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this thing?

Thanks in advance.

**Update_1**

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Dec 22 11:39 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.596746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.637319] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.637320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.637538] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.707824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    2.716214] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.716509] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.757293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: a0:51:0b:10:56:12
[    2.825867] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.994771] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    4.655464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.770454] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.836287] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  509.023878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: No beacon heard and the time event is over already...
[ 1111.101929] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

**Update_2**

```
          Cell 06 - Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"home_wifi"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000003ad4f99d19a
                    Extra: Last beacon: 5568ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0008416C656E62793230
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEE1117FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B000600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050400F6127A
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4303000000
```

Comment: Please edit your post to show the result of the terminal commands: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and also:`dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you. I edited the Q.

Comment: Let's see if we can discern what is unique about your home wifi. Please run: `sudo iwlist wlo1 scan` Just show your home wifi and redact the MAC address like this: `Address: xxxxxx`

Comment: @chili555 Updated the Q.

Answer (score 1):

TKIP? Not only is TKIP quite insecure, but many wireless drivers, as well as old Chili, hate hate hate TKIP.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

**EDIT**: If you are in a situation where changing the router is not feasible, a landlord, university, etc., you may get a connection even with TKIP with a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi swcrypto=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: The issue that I do not have access to the router/router settings. It is not mine. I will go over the answer you have mentioned, but is there any solution without interacting with the router? Because I called the landlord and she said that she do not want to change anything.

Comment: I tried setting the regulatory domain but it did not help.

Comment: See my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: :( :( after doing so (`echo "options iwlwifi swcrypto=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
`) I lost also my hotspot connection. Now I am getting `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` in chrome for every network :(. I removed the line and reboot > my hotspot is back to work but the `home wifi` is still not.